# Ruby: call method of current class without polymorphism

Tags: ruby, oop, polymorphism, overriding

How can I force method_2 to call A::method_1 ?

```
class A
  def method_1
    puts "A"
  end

  def method_2
    method_1 #call A::method_1 only if this is instance of A
  end
end

class B < A
  def method_1
    puts "B"
  end
end

B.new.method_2
```

In usual implementation method_1 is overrided. Is there a way to call overrided methods of A?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Research of language scope.

Comment: `method_1 if self.class == A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's kind of weird question, you still can implement exactly what you want with this code:

```
class A
  def method_1
    puts "A"
  end

  def method_2
    A.instance_method(:method_1).bind(self).call
  end
end

class B < A
  def method_1
    puts "B"
  end
end

puts B.new.method_2
# => A
```

Since you have instance of `B`, `method_1` is overwritten. But you can point directly to `A#method_1` via `A.instance_method`.

`instance_method` returns `UnboundMethod` which means it doesn't have a reference to `self`. So, you need to bind it with `.bind(self)`.

Then you call a method with `.call`.

Comment: Ruby is pretty flexible. Depending on what you need, you can get the most base method with something like this `method = b.method(:method_1)` and `method = method.super_method while method.super_method`